# How to use image hash as filename for downloaded images?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library, imagehash

In Python I want to save an image to file. The filenames should be hashes, generated by `imagehash.average_hash()`. Using `ls -l` I see files but they are empty:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 lorem  lorem     0  8 Sep 16:20 c4c0bcb49890bcfc.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lorem  lorem   837  8 Sep 16:19 minimal.py
```

Code:

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
import imagehash
import shutil

def safe_to_file(url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
    image_hash = ''
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10, stream=True)
    try:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            image_hash = str(imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(r.raw))) + '.jpg'
            print(image_hash)
            with open(image_hash, 'wb') as f:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return image_hash

# Random jpg picture
url = 'https://cdn.ebaumsworld.com/mediaFiles/picture/1035099/85708057.jpg'
safe_to_file(url)
```

I would expect images which aren't empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're not getting any exceptions being printed, I would assume it's because `r.raw` is not a "file-like object" that `copyfileobj()` requires (or is empty if it is).

Comment: It's also possible that the `Image.open(r.raw)` consumed all the image data so there's nothing left for `copyfileobj()` to read. Without and [mcve] it's hard to tell...

Comment: @martineau: Of course that’s it: any image analysis will have to have read at least **some** of the stream, which is then unavailable to `copyfileobj`.

Comment: sorry, just added a minimum reproducible example. @martineau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, the creation of the `PIL.Image` object consumes and downloads all the image data from the url, so there's nothing for `shutil.copyfileobj()` to consume.

The code below seems to avoid that problem by explicitly saving the `Image` object with the desired hash-based filename. I added comments to indicate the significant changes.

```
import imagehash
from PIL import Image
import requests
#import shutil


def safe_to_file(url):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) '
                             'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                             'Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
    image_hash = ''
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10, stream=True)
    try:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            img = Image.open(r.raw)  # ADDED
            image_hash = str(imagehash.average_hash(img)) + '.jpg'  # CHANGED.
            print('saving image:', image_hash)
            img.save(image_hash)  # ADDED
#            with open(image_hash, 'wb') as f:  # REMOVED
#                r.raw.decode_content = True    # REMOVED
#                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)   # REMOVED
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return image_hash

# Random jpg picture
url = 'https://cdn.ebaumsworld.com/mediaFiles/picture/1035099/85708057.jpg'
safe_to_file(url)
```

`c4c0bcb49890bcfc.jpg` file it created:

[image: image file created]